# Unwind Segue - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, app

No aplicativo que estou trabalhando, tem uma ViewController onde o usuário se loga, após se logar, é mostrado um AlertView com boas vindas, e nesse momento, teria de voltar para a tela principal, de onde o usuário veio.
Nos tutoriais que vi, o Unwind so são feitos a partir de um botão ou algo do tipo. Como faria para voltar a tela, em um determinado evento.

Answer (score 0):

Bom amigo, pelo que entendi, o usuario após se logar teria que para a tela principal do App. 
  Sua pergunta carece de mais informações técnicas para uma orientação mais precisa.

Seu app faz uso de navegação por Storyboard, ou é feito programaticamente?
 A tela de login é chamada por modal, push ou é um AlertView customizado para ser uma tela de login ?

Assumindo que sua tela de login é outra UIViewController, e requer uma apenas "1 passo" para voltar para a principal, você pode tentar um desses métodos abaixo:

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
popoverPresentationController
dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil
popViewControllerAnimated:
```

Caso tenha interesse em usar um UnWind Segue, você pode conferir esse tutorial:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/